# Cannot realloc c array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have a structs like so

```
typedef struct ll_node {
    uint data;
    struct ll_node* next;
} ll_node;

typedef struct {
    ll_node* head;
    uint     count;
} linked_list;

typedef struct {
    linked_list* lists;
    uint list_size
} Context;
```

And I need to be able to have lists grow dynamically from context. Here is how I'm adding a linked list to my lists array

```
void add_list(Context* c) {
    if (c->list_size == 0) {
        c->lists = malloc(sizeof(linked_list));
    } else {
        realloc(c->lists, sizeof(linked_list) * (c->list_size + 1));
    }
    linked_list_init(c->lists[c->list_size]);
    list_size++;
}
```

The problem comes in whenever I realloc. I lose the data that is not the most current index in lists. So if c->lists[0] contained 1==>1==>2 then it would be gone and c->lists[1] would be initialized and ready for linked list functions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is wrong

```
realloc(c->lists, sizeof(linked_list) * (c->list_size + 1));
```

should be

```
c->lists = realloc(c->lists, sizeof(linked_list) * (c->list_size + 1));
```

and I would recommend a safe way of doing this

```
void *clists;

clists = realloc(c->lists, sizeof(linked_list) * (c->list_size + 1));
if (clists == NULL)
    handleCurrentErrorProbablyRetryOrAbortFillingTheListAndCleanupResources();
c->lists = clists
```

this way you wont overwrite the valid `c->list` in case of failure.

**tip**: don't update `c->list_size` unless the `malloc` or `realloc` was successful, you need to check that the return non-`NULL`.

Comment: BTW, you should test against failure of `malloc` & `realloc`